# C++ Syntax for new Struct in Templated Class

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

I am having trouble with some code in a member function definition.

from .h file:

```
//This is a private type
struct node {
node   *next;
node   *prev;
T      *o;
};
```

The code producing error from the .cpp file:

```
template <typename T>
void Dlist<T>::function(T *o)
{
node newV = new node;
....
}
```

which I thought was the proper syntax for declaring a struct and I got a ""node was not declared in this scope" error.

Then I tried:

```
Dlist<T>::node *victim;
```

and I got a "newV was not declared in this scope" error, which puzzled me even more as the line itself is a declaration.

I am including the .cpp inside the .h file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`new X` returns a pointer to an `X`, so you need to assign the result of a call to `new node` to a `node*`, not a `node`:

```
template <typename T>
void Dlist<T>::function(T *o)
{
  node* newV = new node;
....
}
```

See an example [here](http://ideone.com/PthbQW).

Note that the use of raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects is quite tricky and bound to result in memory management errors. I would suggest using [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) or automatically allocated variables (non pointers).

```
struct node {
  std::unique_ptr<node>   next;
  std::unique_ptr<node>   prev;
  std::unique_ptr<T>      o;
};
```

Comment: If the guy doesn't even know about pointers, there's no way in hell he'll cope with managing his own memory. No smart pointers -> downvote.

Comment: @DeadMG I was trying to fix the immediate problem. I will add something about smart pointers.